# Spring Cloud Kinesis Binder How to Handle ERROR for Producer and Consumer - As per Documentation it is Not working

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I have followed the below documentation and I have a producer and Consumer working perfectly fine with Kinesis Stream. I would like to understand how to handle the ERROR in Producer (Source) and Consumer (Processor) in case of any exception happens.

**I have tried below approaches as per Spring Stream Error Handling Documentations:**

1. I have tried using
   @ServiceActivator("input-stream.input-stream-group.erros") - this works, but my "input-stream" is a dynamic name in each production environment as per the policy I should append a production environment name while defining the Data Stream. This is preferred way but **How to solve this?**
2. I have tried using @ServiceActivator("errorChannel") - this is not working means the ERROR is catching and printing if I introduce a
   method for this and put a Logger but ERROR is throwing due to below rethrow in `org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler` (line 53-68)

   ```
       catch (Exception e) {
       if (e instanceof MessagingException) {
           throw (MessagingException) e;
       }
       else {
           throw new MessagingException(requestMessage,
                   "Exception thrown while invoking "
                           + this.invocableHandlerMethod.getShortLogMessage(),
                   e);
       }
   }
   ```
3. I have Autowired a MessageChannel in the same name of "errorChannel"
   and while Catching the Exception I have prepared a Message and send
   to it, but same as above in the ServiceActivator method behaves.

How do I can handle and solve this? Please suggest and help me.

Documentation: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc#error-channels

Comment: Please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63270755/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-parameterize-specified-error-channel-destination, if it helps. Thank you.

Comment: @Deepak Chaudhary - This is good for consumers. How can we do for Producer any idea? How can I inject an error on the producer side to test it as well? The binder documentation I followed but the "errorChannel" approach using StreamListener or ServiceActivator is  not working. I am throwing a RuntimeException explicitly and trying.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the benefit of all who are facing the issue. If you miss the comment section. The answer from Deepak Chaudhary is working fine for the Consumer.

Please checkout stackoverflow.com/questions/63270755/…, if it helps. Thank you. – Deepak Chaudhary

Thank you Deepak

would like to understand how can we do this for producer.